# when page load action result called twice in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

when I load the page first hi action result and view and layout and again action result.

```
public ActionResult UploadPricedata()
        {
            oLoggedinUser = Session["LoginUser"] as List<Users>;
            if (oLoggedinUser == null) return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "TransBankUsers");
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Also, is the the entire method? oLoggedinUser  and User are undefined.

Comment: when I add layout page to my UploadPricedata view then UploadPricedata actionresult called twice, without layout page working perfectly

Comment: Please show the code for your layout view and UploadPricedata view.